# White edges on React page, backgroundColor not covering edges

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, background-color

I've used Gatsby before a few years ago, and it's totally different now.
Before I also didn't use styled-components, this time I'm trying to use styled components and skip the css/sass part.

You can see the image attached for the white edges I am referring to.

Any ideas on why this might be happening would be a great help too.

Just editting the basic landing page that gatsby comes with, I'm trying to add a black background to my website, like in dark mode. The problem is that white edges keep showing up on all 4 sides of the site. I've made margins 0, setting minWidth and minHeight to a 100% do not work and result in overflow, neither does fitContainer work (leaves the white edges). Setting the attributes to fill, contain and cover also do not work.

I want my background to cover all the edges, i.e cover the entire background of the site whilst not overflowing, remaining the size of the window it is open in.

Here is my styled-component:
`const pageStyles = { color: "#232129", backgroundColor: "black", backgroundSize: "fill", margin: 0, width: "100%", minHeight: "100%", padding: 96, fontFamily: "-apple-system, Roboto, sans-serif, serif", }`

and this is where I'm using it
`const IndexPage1 = () => { return ( <main style={pageStyles}> .....`

Comment: Have you set `margin: 0` on `<body>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your page has the default margin on body and you just need to set it to 0. Here's a sample page where you can toggle body's margin between default and 0.

```css
main {
  background: darkgrey;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

body {
  background: blue;
}

.no-margin {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <button onClick="document.body.classList.toggle('no-margin')">Toggle Body Margin</button>
</main>
```

Comment: That works brilliantly thanks! I'm still confused why it doesn't work when I set the styled-component's margin: 0. Should be the same thing, right?

Comment: Setting it on your component doesn't work because the margin isn't on your component. It's the default margin on `<body>`.